# I don't get why my form isn't working

Tags: php, forms, email, nl2br

My code did work few minutes ago.
I didn't change anything, I just tried again for tests, now nothing is working.
I just wanted to do a very simple form to email :

HTML

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post" id="inscription">
    <input name="nom" type="text" id="nom" placeholder="Nom">
    <input name="prenom" type="text" id="prenom" placeholder="Prénom">
    <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
    <input name="tel" type="tel" id="tel" placeholder="01.23.45.67.89">
    <input name="company" type="text" id="company" placeholder="Nom de l'entreprise">
    <input name="nb-personne" type="text" id="nb-personne" placeholder="Nombre de personne">
    <textarea name="comment" cols="15" rows="6" id="comment"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="JE M'INSCRIS*" class="submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
$ToEmail = 'ptusseau@histrasbourg.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Inscription SOIREE BRESILIENNE<hr/>'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$mailheader .="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$mailheader .="Content-type: text/html; charset=utf=8\r\n";

$MESSAGE_BODY = "Nom: ".$_POST["nom"]."";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Prénom: ".$_POST["prenom"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Tél: ".$_POST["tel"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Entreprise: ".$_POST["company"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Nombre de personne: ".$_POST["nb-personne"]."";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Commentaire: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"])."";
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader); 

// METTRE UN MERCI.HTML 
include("merci.html");
exit(0);
```

I wanted to make a simple email, with 
 in HTML just before any new line (prenom, email, tel, etc.).
But I don't know how to do, I don't understand .nl2br actually ...
And it doesn't send an email anymore, anyway.

Comment: Well does it give an error, what does mail return (it returns boolean true or false)..

Comment: No error, it loads correctly merci.html and that's all. No mail.
I tried on 3 inbox, everything works perfectly, but not my code :(
I don't get how return true or false ... on what ?

Answer (score 0):

- Inspect, verify and filter POST data to see whether data is coming through correctly
- Verify you can send mails from the server you are using and configuration (SMTP etc.) is correctly set up
- Consider [using a mail library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497767/php-newbie-email-library) instead of manually working with error-prone mail headers, body contents and all that is involved
- Your emails might be [classified as spam](https://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam) and thus not getting through

Comment: Also, you are not securing the input ? Maybe the quote caracter is the problem ? You should at least have a `addslashes` function around your `$_POST`.

Comment: Could you help me to inspect the POST data ? Actually I've near no knowledge of PHP. I just wanted to send a basic mail... I thought this was possible. And I HAVE to succeed, it's my first job in my company :(

Comment: When I ECHO my "$_POST["nom"]" or anything else, it works ... I guess this is mail() which doesn't work.