# bootstrap form - cant add fields

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a twitter bootstrap modern business website and would like to add two fields to the form. The form says its been sent but nothing is received.

Heres my form and contact-me.php

```html
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Full Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                   
                    
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Foo:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="foo" required data-validation-required-message="foo.">
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Foo2:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="foo2" required data-validation-required-message="foo2.">
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                                        
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Phone Number:</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Email Address:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Message:</label>
                            <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="success"></div>
                    <!-- For success/fail messages -->
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
                </form>
```

and my contact-me-php

```
<?php
// check if fields passed are empty
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['foo'])         ||
   empty($_POST['foo2'])        ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$foo = $_POST['foo'];
$foo2 = $_POST['foo2'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// create email body and send it    
$to = 'foo@foo.com'; // PUT YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS HERE
$email_subject = "Modern Business Contact Form:  $name"; // EDIT THE EMAIL SUBJECT LINE HERE
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website's contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nfoo: $foo\n\nfoo2: $foo2\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@your-domain.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Inspect, verify and filter POST data to see whether data is coming through correctly
- Verify you can send mails from the server you are using and configuration (SMTP etc.) is correctly set up
- Consider [using a mail library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497767/php-newbie-email-library) instead of manually working with error-prone mail headers, body contents and all that is involved
- Your emails might be [classified as spam](https://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam) and thus not getting through

Comment: Hi Elias – thanks for that. 
All was working before I added the two new fields. Any advice on how to Inspect, verify and filter POST data.

Comment: Use dump functions (e.g.[var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump), [print_r](http://php.net/print_r)) to inspect, verify the outputted data and the data you sent. Filtering is to prevent [header injection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11040786/1777956), which is currently possible in your script.

Comment: I have removed the validation section from contact-me.php. The form now sends but the two new fields are empty. Thanks again for your help.I should have said my knowledge of php is quite limited but i am keen to learn   :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a "name" attribute to your inputs. They are not valid controls, [source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I put firebug on and found out I was missing the POST data. After a bit of head scratching I found I had to edit my contact_me.js as well (it helpfully say not to edit it in the template) Thanks again!